# How to get the name of variables of the first level of a list?

Tags: r, list

I have a list in `R` called `myLst`. This list contains different dataframes with the name:

```
myLst$'2014'$total
myLst$'2015'$total
myLst$'2016'$total
myLst$'2017'$total
```

How can I get the info of the first level of the list, such as `['2014', '2015', '2016', '2017']`

Comment: `as.integer(names(myLst))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `parse_number`

```
readr::parse_number(names(myLst))
#[1] 2014 2015 2016 2017
```

#### data

```
myLst <- setNames(as.list(1:4), paste0("myLst$'", 2014:2017, "'$total"))
```

Comment: thanks, another question: how can I read each dataframe in a loop?

Comment: @emax  You can  use `paste` i.e. `for(nm in 2014:2017) print(myLst[[nm]])` assuming that the structure you have is the one I have in my mind

Comment: I would like to get each dataframe in a loop without knowing the real value

Comment: @emax  In that case use index i.e. `for(i in seq_along(myLst)) print(myLst[[i]])`